# How can I return a configured App in Actix-Web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm using actix-web to create a httpserver with state/data embedded in it. But vscode show me that the `create_app` function has wrong arguments in its return value type definition `App<AppState>`:

```
pub struct App<T, B>
wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 1
expected 2 type argumentsrustc(E0107)
```

app.rs:

```
use crate::api;
use crate::model::DbExecutor;
use actix::prelude::Addr;
use actix_web::{error, http::Method, middleware::Logger, web, App, HttpResponse};

pub struct AppState {
    pub db: Addr<DbExecutor>,
}

pub fn create_app(db: Addr<DbExecutor>) -> App<AppState> {
    App::new().data(AppState { db }).service(
        web::resource("/notes/").route(web::get().to(api::notes))
    );
}
```

main.rs:

```
fn main() {
    HttpServer::new(move || app::create_app(addr.clone()))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:3000")
        .expect("Can not bind to '127.0.0.1:3000'")
        .start();
}
```

As return type of "service" method is "Self" which is type actix_web::App, I tried modify return type to App (without generic parameter) but still got error, what should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `App` takes two generic type arguments, [`App<AppEntry, Body>`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/2.0.0-alpha.2/actix_web/struct.App.html), you've only given one.

Second, `AppState` is not `AppEntry`.

Third, instantiating `App` outside actix-web is hard, if not impossible, as the types you need from actix-web are not public.

Instead, you should use [configure](https://actix.rs/docs/application/#configure) to achieve the same, here is a simplified example:

```rust
use actix_web::web::{Data, ServiceConfig};
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};

fn main() {
    let db = String::from("simplified example");

    HttpServer::new(move || App::new().configure(config_app(db.clone())))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:3000")
        .expect("Can not bind to '127.0.0.1:3000'")
        .run()
        .unwrap();
}

fn config_app(db: String) -> Box<dyn Fn(&mut ServiceConfig)> {
    Box::new(move |cfg: &mut ServiceConfig| {
        cfg.app_data(db.clone())
            .service(web::resource("/notes").route(web::get().to(notes)));
    })
}

fn notes(db: Data<String>) -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(["notes from ", &db].concat())
}
```

Read more about `ServiceConfig` in the [api documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.7/actix_web/web/struct.ServiceConfig.html).

Comment: That does not really answer the question, does it? Your code basically replaces the code in the original question, achieving the same. But it does not answer why the return type App<AppState> is not accepted / right.

Comment: @inzanez updated the answer to explain why returning `App<AppState>` is wrong and answers "what should I do?"

Answer (score 0):

its really easy but you need to import AppEntry
and the problem is that AppEntry not exported by actix_web

so you need to update the original code of the package

so go to /lib.rs by pressing on ctrl + right Click on actix_web;
then add the next line after pub mod rt;

```
pub mod app_service ;
```

then you need to update the cache so firstly

```
cargo clean
cargo update
cargo fetch
cargo build
```

now everything is good so you could import AppEntry using this syntax

```
use actix_web::app_service::AppEntry;
```

after importing app entry you could do what ever you want by structing your code to mvc or doing what every you want

Comment: use actix_web::{Responder,HttpResponse,get,HttpServer,App,app_service::AppEntry};


#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}
fn setup_routes_and_controllers(app:App<AppEntry>)->App<AppEntry>{
    app.service(hello)
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main()->std::io::Result<()>{
    
     HttpServer::new( || {
       let app =  
        App::new();
       setup_routes_and_controllers(app)
     }).
     bind("")?
    .run()
    .await
}

Comment: AppEntry is not exposed for public consumption