# How to move actix_web startup into a separate function?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have some actix_web stuff wrapped in a module and pulled in by my REST api functions, except for too much kick-starting boilerplate:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .service((api1, api2, api3)))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8081))?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

I'd like to get the low-level parts out of sight and have only the business logic stuff (bind-address & rest-apis) visible. I.e. simplify `main()` to one of:

```rust
    web::init((api1, api2, api3))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8081))?
        .run()
        .await

    web::init(|app| app.service((api1, api2, api3)))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8081))?
        .run()
        .await

    web::run(("127.0.0.1", 8081), (api1, api2, api3))?
```

But just refactoring this into a separate function changes everything. Whatever I try, I always stumble across many suddenly needed generic parameters, moving the tuple into the closure is suddenly considered to cross thread boundaries, etc. How to write such an `init` or `run` function?

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: If you want to encapsulate calls like `.app_data()`, `.wrap()`, and `.service()` in a separate function. You should use `.configure()` as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57457202/how-can-i-return-a-configured-app-in-actix-web). I would not recommend trying to return a `App` or `HttpServer`.

Comment: @Stargateur How to write such an init or run function? One that can be called as in my 2nd box (or similar.)

Comment: @Daniel My link is correct (not sure where you see anything logging related). Using `.configure()` is the way Actix-web has designed its APIs, which puts the business logic in a separate function. The opposite starts to get messy. The best I'd suggest (using your third desired syntax) would be [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c93b0545cd29a28957244df96b492fb3).

Comment: Or I guess you can build around how `.configure()` works and make a function based on that like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=200009abedf8a310cdc9f1880d45f26e).

Comment: @kmdreko Sorry about the wrong url, my bad. Your code-snippet rocks, this is wonderful, thank you! Actually the closure can be just `|| (api1, api2, api3)`. If you provide it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In case the playground by @kmdreko ever disappears, here's what I turned it into. Not sure why the where clause has to be split into two generics, but it only works like that.

```rust
/// If we ever need more services than it can take from a tuple, we need to add services2... and .service(services2())...
pub async fn run<F, S>(host: &str, port: u16, services: F) -> std::io::Result<()>
where
    F: Fn() -> S + Clone + Send + 'static,
    S: HttpServiceFactory + 'static,
{
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::new("%bb %Ts %s %r").log_target("http"))
            .service(services())
    })
    .bind((host, port))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

For some reason `cargo +nightly fmt` (I compile with stable, but use latest formatter) wraps the caller's tuple into braces (which it doesn't do for other single-expression closures.)

```rust
run("127.0.0.1", 8081, || (api1, api2, api3)).await
```